# passing a 3D pointer array to a function

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

so i'm having problems making this test program work. so my goal is to make and initialize a 3D array in my main function, then create a pointer to that array. afterwards i'm trying to pass the pointer to a function and then print out the elements in the array so that i can see it works. my problem arises when trying to pass the pointer array tho. Can any of you guys see were im going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//declare test function
void test (int*);

int main(){

    //declare array and pointer
    int array[2][3][2];
    int (*p)[2][3][2] = &array;

    int i,j,k;

    //initialize array
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                array[i][j][k] = 0;
            }       
        }
    }

    //print array
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                printf("%d\n", array[i][j][k]);
            }       
        }
    }
    printf("----------------------------\n\n");
    //pass pointer array into test function
    test(p);    
}


void test(int (*array2)[2][3][2]){
    int i, j, k;
    //run thru each element in the pointer array and print
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                printf("%d\n", array2[i][j][k]);
            }       
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: `void test(int array2[2][3][2])` and dump the `p` thing by calling `test(array);` and change the function prototype to match its implementation.

Comment: i can do that yea, but it wont be sending a pointer of the array. im trying to figure out how to do this so that i can later modify the array in a function thru a pointer

Comment: The array passed decays to a pointer. The function definition tells how to use it.

Comment: omg wesome! i just tested it and passed just the array, modified it a bit, and printed it back in the main function and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The array passed decays to a pointer, and the function definition tells how to use it. The function does not need to know the top array dimension to index correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int array2[][3][2]);

void test(int array2[][3][2])
{
    printf("In function %d\n", array2[1][1][1]);
    array2[1][1][1] = 42;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int array[2][3][2] = {0};
    array[1][1][1] = 99;
    test(array);
    printf("In main %d\n", array[1][1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
In function 99
In main 42
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use:

```
int array[2][3][2];
int (*p)[2][3][2] = &array;
```

Then, the line

```
            printf("%d\n", array2[i][j][k]);
```

in `test` needs to be:

```
            printf("%d\n", (*array2)[i][j][k]);
```

You can also use:

```
int array[2][3][2];
int (*p)[3][2] = array;
```

Then, you need to change the function to

```
void test(int (*array2)[3][2]){
```

or

```
void test(int array2[][3][2]){
```

which will allow you to use:

```
            printf("%d\n", array2[i][j][k]);
```